# Slow python file I:O; Ruby runs better than this; Got the wrong language?

Tags: python, ruby, regex, text

Please advise - I'm going to use this asa learning point. I'm a beginner.

I'm splitting a 25mb file into several smaller file.

A Kindly guru here gave me a Ruby sript. It works beautifully fast. So, in order to learn I mimicked it with a python script. This runs like a three-legged cat (slow). I wonder if anyone can tell me why?

My python script

```
    ##split a file into smaller files
###########################################
def splitlines (file) :
        fileNo=0001
        outFile=open("C:\\Users\\dunner7\\Desktop\\Textomics\\Media\\LexisNexus\\ele\\newdocs\%s.txt" % fileNo, 'a') ## open file to append 
        fh = open(file, "r") ## open the file for reading
        mylines = fh.readlines() ### read in lines
        for line in mylines: ## for each line
                        if re.search("Copyright ", line): # if the line is equal to the regex
                            outFile.close()  ##  close the file
                            fileNo +=1  #and add one to the filename, starting to read lines in again
                        else: # otherwise
                            outFile=open("C:\\Users\\dunner7\\Desktop\\Textomics\\Media\\LexisNexus\\ele\\newdocs\%s.txt" % fileNo, 'a') ## open file to append 
                            outFile.write(line)          ## then append it to the open outFile          
        fh.close()
```

The guru's Ruby 1.9 script

```
g=0001
f=File.open(g.to_s + ".txt","w")
open("corpus1.txt").each do |line|
  if line[/\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS/]
    f.close
    f=File.open(g.to_s + ".txt","w")
    g+=1
  end
  f.print line
end
```

Comment: Can you post some numbers regarding speed?

Comment: The scripts do different things.  The Python script opens a new file for almost every line it's writes.  That's certainly slow, but what do you expect?

Comment: The Ruby script also opens multiple files for output.

Comment: But only after the regex matches, whereas the python script really does it for every line.

Comment: @Dat: The issue though, is that the ruby script only opens a new file when it matches a certain pattern, whereas the python script re-opens the file to append to almost every iteration through the loop.

Comment: If you want a real performance comparison, you need to compare your two approaches with doing so in Perl. That said, it seems pretty um, subperformant, to pre-read all the lines into memory just to write them all out again.  Return to the read-a-line,write-a-line model.

Comment: As long as memory suffices, reading the whole file into memory *is* probably the fastest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The Python code might be slow due to regex and not IO.</strike> Try

```
def splitlines (file) :
  fileNo=0001
  outFile=open("newdocs/%s.txt" % fileNo, 'a') ## open file to append 
  reg = re.compile("Copyright ")
  for line in open(file, "r"): 
    if reg.search("Copyright ", line): # if the line is equal to the regex
      outFile.close()  ##  close the file
      outFile=open("newdocs%s.txt" % fileNo, 'a') ## open file to append 
      fileNo +=1  #and add one to the filename, starting to read lines in again

    outFile.write(line)          ## then append it to the open outFile
```

Several notes

- Always use / instead of \ for path name
- If regex is used repeatedly, compile it
- Do you need re.search? or re.match?

UPDATE:

- @Ed. S: point taken
- @Winston Ewert: code updated to be closer to the original Ruby code

Comment: The day that applying a regular expression to a small amount of text is slower than reading a file from disk is the day I stop using regular expressions.  I think you are wrong about your guess on this one.

Comment: if you modify the code not to reopen the file constantly, it'll be much faster.

Answer (score 6):

There are many reasons why your script is slow -- the main reason being that you reopen the outputfile for almost every line you write.  Since the old file gets implicitly closed on opening a new one (due to Python garbage collection), the write buffer is flushed for every single line you write, which is quite expensive.

A cleaned up and corrected version of your script would be

```
def file_generator():
    file_no = 1
    while True:
        f = open(r"C:\Users\dunner7\Desktop\Textomics\Media"
                 r"\LexisNexus\ele\newdocs\%s.txt" % file_no, 'a')
        yield f
        f.close()
        file_no += 1

def splitlines(filename):
    files = file_generator()
    out_file = next(files)
    with open(filename) as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if "Copyright " in line:
                out_file = next(files)
            out_file.write(line)
        out_file.close()
```

Comment: +1 Figuring out that code forced me to learn a couple of newer python features that I was not previously aware of. One of the many reasons I like SO.

Comment: Just fascinated someone had to figure out my code!! I'm a shrink!!, think I should change careers ??? No, ok.

Comment: @Rosser - Not your code - It was clear what was going wrong there. I had not previously seen the `with` `as` construct that Sven used for reading files. It's not super new to python, but I had not come across it before.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the reason your script is so slow is that you open a new file descriptor for each line. If you look at your guru's ruby script, it closes and opens the output file only if your separator matches.

In contrast to that, your python script opens a new file descriptor for every line you read (and btw, does not close them). Opening a file requires talking to the kernel, so this is relatively slow.

Another change I would suggest is to change

```
fh = open(file, "r") ## open the file for reading
mylines = fh.readlines() ### read in lines
for line in mylines: ## for each line
```

to

```
fh = open(file, "r")
for line in fh:
```

With this change, you do not read the whole file into memory, but only block after block. Although it should not matter with a 25MiB file, it will hurt you with *big* files and is good practice (and less code ;)).

Answer (score 0):

rosser,

Don't use names of built-in objects as identifiers in a code (file, splitlines)

The following code respects the effect of your own code: an **out_file** is closed without the line containing 'Copyright ' that constitutes the signal of closing

The use of the function **writelines()** is intended to obtain a faster execution than with a repetition of `out_file.write(line)`

The `if li:` block is there to trigger the closing of **out_file** in case the last line of the read file doesn't contains 'Copyright '

```
def splitfile(filename, wordstop, destrep, file_no = 1, li = []):
    with open(filename) as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if wordstop in line:
                with open(destrep+str(file_no)+'.txt','w') as f:
                    f.writelines(li)
                file_no += 1
                li = []
            else:
                li.append(line)
        if li:
            with open(destrep+str(file_no)+'.txt','w') as f:
                f.writelines(li)
```